# What will happen if the record searched by ID doesn't exist when I use Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

The Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid).

The `fun getTopicEntity` will return a flow based the parameter `topicId`, I wonder whether the app will crash if the record based input `topicId` doesn't exist.

In my mind, `fun getTopicEntity(topicId: String): Flow<TopicEntity>` requires to return `Flow<TopicEntity>`,  `Flow<TopicEntity>` will not be generated if the record doesn't exist, so the app will crash. Is it right?

**Code A**

```
@Dao
interface TopicDao {
    @Query(
        value = """
        SELECT * FROM topics
        WHERE id = :topicId
    """
    )
    fun getTopicEntity(topicId: String): Flow<TopicEntity>

    ...
}


class OfflineFirstTopicsRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val topicDao: TopicDao,
    private val network: NiaNetworkDataSource,
) : TopicsRepository {
  
    override fun getTopic(id: String): Flow<Topic> =
        topicDao.getTopicEntity(id).map { it.asExternalModel() }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: If Room can't find the thing, it will return null. If you assume it won't be null, yeah it will bonk you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Room can't find the queried id (TopicEntry doesn't exist), than it throws a NullPointerException. From the official docs:

> Keep nullability in mind when choosing a return type, as it affects
> how the query method handles empty tables:
>
> When the return type is Flow, querying an empty table throws a null
> pointer exception.
>
> When the return type is Flow<T?>, querying an empty table emits a null
> value.
>
> When the return type is Flow<List>, querying an empty table emits
> an empty list.

So if you think it is possible that it returns null, you should make the return type nullable `fun getTopicEntity(topicId: String): Flow<TopicEntity?>` and make a null check or use something like `topicDao.getTopicEntity(id).filterNotNull().map { it.asExternalModel() }`